# Jupyter Notebook - When downloading as html, how do I keep the styling of the tables?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

When I run the below in a Jupyter notebook using Python 3, the table displays exactly how I want it. e.g., shading of columns, minimal gridlines, `Value` column is right justified.

However, when I download the file as HTML (e.g. click File > Download As > HTML (.html)), the formatting of the table is gone. How do I keep this styling?

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def format_dollar(x):
    return "${:,.0f}".format(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Region': ['West', 'West', 'South', 'South', 'South', 'South'],
              'Product': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
              'Value': [10000, 200, 15, 13, 100, 100],
              'Value2': [11, 13, 1200, 100, 30, 10]})
df = df.pivot_table(values=['Value', 'Value2'],
               index=['Product', 'Region'])
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(format_dollar)

display(df)
```